# Need help to call multiple javascript fetch GET

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code multiple dependent fetch get requests. Here number fetch call is a variable and each new request has previous response dependency

i try below pseudocode code, just need to set finalResult var after last fetch call

```
var finalResult = null;

af = async () => {
     Promise.resolve() 
    .then(x => console.log("first then"))
    .then(x_FromPreviousResponse => console.log("second then"))
    .
    .
    . 
    .then(z_FromPreviousResponse => finalResult = z_FromPreviousResponse)
     Promise.resolve()
    
}

af()
```

kindly give me code example or pseudocode

Comment: Can you also use `async-await` or you're looking for the answer using `.then` only?

Comment: You should be more specific. A recursive function can help here. Are you calling always the same url? Is the url present in the answer?

Comment: @mandy8055, actually i have a setup form where i can read all the api end point url and request param name .  Now i have n number of url how i can call them one after another but in a sync way

Comment: @Adriano, thank you so much, so far your idea is best suite to me, definitely i will try that

Comment: @Sahab I have attached a working sample along with the pseudocode in my answer. That will serve your purpose. You can take a look

Comment: This is not an optimal way to perform a fetch. You need to figure out a way to send the fetch separately from one another because here your throttle is any request in the sequence that takes long time, everyone after it will be late as well. Crushing for performance. This is why, when you are querying data, you either want to include all the relevant data in the request, describing the request itself, or run separately with the identificator being provided by the application instead of the response of a previous request.

Comment: @Dimitar thank you so much for comments. i actually have to depend on previous response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want code that is able to handle multiple dependent `fetch()` requests:

```
fetch(API_URL_DIARY)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("old", data);
        return data;
    })
    .then(async data => {
        await Promise.all(data.map((e, index, array) => {
            return fetch(API_URL_FOOD_DETAILS + e.foodid)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    array[index] = {...e, ...data};
                    console.log("update");
                })
        }));
        console.log("new", data)
    });
```

`fetch(API_URL_DIARY)` makes the first request. Its response is converted to JSON and logged to the console.

The data is then returned to the next `then()` block.

`Promise.all()` is used to make multiple fetch requests.

Lastly the `map()` function is used to iterate over the data and create a new request.

I also wrote this for more readability:

```
async function getFishAndChips() {
    const fish = await fetch(this.fishApiUrl).then(response => response.json());
    this.fish = fish;

    const fishIds = fish.map(fish => fish.id),
    chipReqOpts = { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({ fishIds }) };

    const chips = await fetch(this.chipsApiUrl, chipReqOpts).then(response => response.json());
    this.chips = chips;
}
```

A more dynamic way could be:

```
function fetchSequentially(url, maxRequests, index = 0, finalResult = []) {
    if (index >= maxRequests) {
        console.log(finalResult);
        return;
    }

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            finalResult.push(data);
            fetchSequentially(url, maxRequests, index + 1, finalResult);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

fetchSequentially('https://api.example.com/resource', 10);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, actually con't use await , also here fish ,chip are fix i need a dynamic way

Comment: hi @Sahab i updated my answer providing a dynamic way

Comment: i beleave some modification on your "dinamic way" will work. accepting your answer. thank you so much for help

Comment: could you post the modification? i'm genuenly curios

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `then` method as shown in the example below to make a new fetch call based on the results of the previous call after the previous call has completed. See the example code below.

```
var finalResult;

fetch('url1')
  .then(response1 => response1.json())
  .then(data1 => {
    return fetch('url2/' + data1.example);
  })
  .then(response2 => response2.json())
  .then(data2 => {
    return fetch('url3/' + data2.example);
  })
  .then(response3 => response3.json())
  .then(data3 => {
    finalResult = data3.finalValue;
    console.log(finalResult);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: hi Huiseong Lim welcome here. thank you so much for answer. can you pls show me how i can do n number of then() call  .then().then(). . . . ..nthThen()

Comment: Using the recursive approach allows you to perform n consecutive fetch calls sequentially.

<code>
var finalResult;
var n = 10;

af = async () => {
  if (index < n) {
    fetch('url')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        n++;
        af();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  } else {
    console.log(finalResult);
  }
}

af();
</code>

Answer (score 1):

You can loop an async function and await the result

Something like this untested example

```js
async function fetchData(url, extractParam) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return extractParam ? data[extractParam] : data;
}


async function sequentialApiCalls(apiList) {
  let nextParam = null;
  for (const api of apiList) {
    // Construct the URL for the current API call
    let url = api.apiUrl;
    if (nextParam !== null) {
      url += `?${api.parmName}=${nextParam}`;
    }
    try {
      // Fetch the data and extract the specified parameter for the next call
      const data = await fetchData(url);
      nextParam = data[api.parmName];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API call failed:', error);
      throw error; // Stop the loop in case of an error
    }
  }
  return nextParam; // Returns the final extracted parameter
}

sequentialApiCalls(apiList)
  .then(finalResult => {
    console.log('Final result:', finalResult);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error in sequential API calls:', error);
  });
```

```html
<script>
const apiList = [
    { apiUrl: "https://example.com/api1", parmName: "api1Parameter" },
    { apiUrl: "https://example.com/api2", parmName: "api2Parameter" },
    { apiUrl: "https://example.com/api3", parmName: "api3Parameter" },
];
</script>
```

Without the async await

```
const apiList = [
    { apiUrl: "https://example.com/api1", parmName: "api1Parameter" },
    { apiUrl: "https://example.com/api2", parmName: "api2Parameter" },
    { apiUrl: "https://example.com/api3", parmName: "api3Parameter" },
];
const process = (allData)  => {
  allData.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item)
  })
};
const saveData = [];
const getData = () => {
  if (apiList.length === 0) process(saveData); // stop
  const { url, parmName } = apiList.pop(); // remove 
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => reponse.json())
  .then(data => { 
    saveData.push(data[parmName]);
    setTimeout(getData,1000); // throttle
    // getData(); // no throttle
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. i am looking for async without await. also looking some recursive way which could be best suite. your answer it a good option for me.

Comment: See update. Just a sequential call of the fetch